# Symfony 2 Security.yml redirect loop and LogicException issues

Tags: security, symfony

OK I think I need hand holding..

This question is a follow on from the previous question:
[Symfony2 img/LdapBundle Bad credentials error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153125/symfony2-img-ldapbundle-bad-credentials-error)

I have split this out as its a different issue. I am getting two different issues relating to the security.yml file as described below.

I have my security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
            imag_ldap:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                intention: authenticate
                provider: ldap
            logout:
                path:           /logout
                target:         /
        restricted_area:
            pattern:          ^/
            #anonymous:        ~ 
    providers:
        ldap:
           id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

    encoders:
        IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser: plaintext

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,               roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

but im getting the following error:
`LogicException: No authentication listener registered for firewall "restricted_area".`

SO i tried the following:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login_firewall:
            pattern:    ^/login$
            anonymous:  ~
            imag_ldap:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                intention: authenticate
                provider: ldap
            logout:
                path:           /logout
                target:         /
        restricted_area:
            pattern:          ^/
            #anonymous:        ~ 
            imag_ldap:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                intention: authenticate
                provider: ldap
            logout:
                path:           /logout
                target:         /
```

but this causes a redirect loop.

Can anyone show me how to get this to work? I am trying to use the https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle ldap bundle to authenticate users..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle#configure-securityyml you should have one firewall with `pattern: ^/` where also the login lives.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        restricted_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:  ~
            imag_ldap:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                intention: authenticate
                provider: ldap
            logout:
                path:           /logout
                target:         /
    providers:
        ldap:
           id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

    encoders:
        IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser: plaintext

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$,         roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,               roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Sites where you don't need authentication you have to include under `acces_control` with `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role. This also applies to the profiler and toolbar in dev-enivironment (actually for FOSUserBundle, but I think this also significant for the LdapBundle). And yeah, I know the symfony documentation says to create a anonymous firewall exclusively for `^/login$`, but if the bundle supports an anonymous-role it is enough to take the exclude it with acces_control as above.

```
    - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

**EDIT**:
And don't forget to import the routing definitions from the bundle and not define them self. see https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle#import-routing

Comment: Thanks just a little bit more debugging and i should have this fixed. Quic Q though - this bundle is int eh vendor dir, not under source and i dont think the route is importing because of it..

Comment: yep not sure why but its not finding a route for ```No route found for "GET /app_dev/login"```

Comment: I've tested with a fresh symfony 2.2.1 install and added `"imag/ldap-bundle": "2.1.*"` as dependency. The bundle lives under `vendor/imag/ldap-bundle/IMAG/LdapBundle/` and after configuring the bundle and importing the routes, `php app/console router:debug` shows me the routes for login, login_check and logout.

Comment: Oh, and in your error, may you forgot the .php after app_dev? => app_dev.php/....